# What would happen in this priority-based round-robin CPU scheduling algorithm case?

Tags: operating-systems, cpu

I've been implementing some kind of CPU Scheduling Algorithms in Python. And I am really confused with one of the cases what'd be implemented in this case.

Let us assume that the time quantum is 10.
If the first come process which came at 0 has a burst time of 7 (simply denoting that it is less than the time quantum). And let us say at 5 another process with a higher priority comes. In this case, would there be a context switching to the one that came later?

Comment: The answer could depend on the algorithm. What does the algorithm say?

Comment: It is the rules of priority-based round-robin algorithm. There is nothing custom. I'm just trying to figure out what would have been output in this case.